# Is there a "universal" JTAG controller peripheral?

Tags: debugging, intel-fpga, jtag, microsemi-fpga

JTAG can be used to read/write data from/to FPGAs. I want to know if there is any device with an interpreter that can be used with user written STAPL files. Basically the peripheral shall wiggle the JTAG signals as required by the commands inside the user script and in this way read/write data from/to the FPGA it is connected to.

Something like this is possible with virtual JTAG with Intel devices and CoreJTAGDebug which is a wrapper around UJTAG macro found in Microsemi devices. However, I can see that the Microsemi support is not clear on this and I suspect that Intel treats STAPL and JAM files and the process I talking about as being obsolete or redundant.

Does a device that I describe exist or those folks working with FPGAs think it is just not worth the effort and has very limited application? Should I give up on the idea of trying to use STAPL files to debug FPGA designs forever and move on with life as it is?

Comment: Not sure how close this to what you are looking for, but [OpenOCD](http://openocd.org/) can work with many popular JTAG adapters and emulators and is quite customizable and extendable to new devices.